# Counting word score from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

The task is to, given the string of words separated by single spaces, calculate the score of each word (a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 etc.) and return the word with the highest score. If the words have the same score, the word appearing first in the given string should be returned. CodeWars trolls me and again I have only one test not proving my code valid and the rest are ok :/

```
function high(x){
  const arr = x.split(' ');
  let score = 0;
  let highestWord = undefined;
  var currentScore = 0;
  arr.map((word) => {
    currentScore = word.split('').reduce((sum, letter) => {
      return sum + letter.charCodeAt(0) - 64;
    }, 0);
    if (currentScore > score) {
      score = currentScore;
      highestWord = word;
    }
  });
  return highestWord;
}
```

Comment: For what input does it fail? Need a [MCVE] of the input and expected output - we can't debug problems we can't see

Comment: Don't use `map()` if you're not assigning the result, use `forEach()`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I don't think challenge sites tell you what input you failed on.

Comment: Without the "desired behavior and a specific problem or error", the question is off-topic, unfortunately. IIRC you can "buy" test cases to see where you're failing, if you want debugging help, you'll need to either figure out a case that illustrates the problem, or buy it

Answer (score 0):

`64` is the base of the ASCII code for `A`, not `a`. Assuming the score is supposed to be case-insensitive, you need to map everything to the same case before calculating the score.

So use

```
const arr = x.toUpperCase().split(" ");
```

to make everything uppercase first.